How do you create a function in Oracle with a lambda parameter?
I don't seem to be finding any documentation on this (and maybe I don't know the Oracle vernacular for this), but I would like to create a function that takes a function: Say, have it pass me a sort function.
When I look at code like this:
LAG(FOO) OVER (PARTITION BY XXX ORDER BY YYY) AS thing

I get the sense that, that's exactly what's going on here ^^ and the OVER clause is the lambda.
Is it possible to do? Am I thinking of this correctly? A working example would be great.

you can't do that.

You can write your own aggregate and analytic functions (the over indicates analytic - the arguments to that aren't a function though), but not sure what's actually what you want, and it's not trivial. You might be able to do something with dynamic SQL, by passing in the name of a function, but that's going to be messy and painful too. Maybe step back to look at what you're trying to do and see if there is a different approach that SQL would support.

You appear to have an XY-problem where you think the solution is to pass a lambda function to another function (which is not possible). What is the actual problem that you are trying to solve? If you provide a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample data; an explanation of the logic that you are trying to implement; and the expected output for that sample data then we might be able to suggest an alternative solution.


Is it possible to do?

No, in other languages functions are first-class objects but in SQL they are not.

You can write your own custom aggregation functions (examples here, here or here) that can also be used as analytic functions (example fiddle). However, you cannot pass custom sort functions.

Ok, that's what I wanted to know
